# I want to clear the fields after jquery clone of table rows

Tags: php, jquery, clone, rows

I use below jquery code to clone the table rows for my simple invoicing application:
What I want is when the tr is cloned the 2 input fields should be empty price and qty, I will greatly appriciate for help on this, thanks in advance:-

Jquery code:

```
function autoCalcSetup() {
    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire: true, decimalPlaces: 2, emptyAsZero: true});
    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 2});
}
autoCalcSetup();
$('button[name=remove]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form')
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    autoCalcSetup();
});


$('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
    var $top = $table.find('tr[name=line_items]').first();
    var $bottom = $table.find('tr[name=endin_colz]').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);
    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.insertBefore($bottom);
    autoCalcSetup();

});
```

```
<tr name="line_items">
  <td><button name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sn">Remove</button></td>
  <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="productname[]" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
               <option>Select...</option>
               <option>Barcode Machine</option>
<option>Snap frame A4</option>
<option>Snap frame A3</option>
<option>Snap frame A2</option>
<option>Snap frame A1</option>
<option>Snap frame A0</option>
<option>Gazebo Aluminum Foldable</option>
<option>Key Cabinet 24 keys</option>
<option>Vinyl Roll</option>
               </select>

       <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="particulars[]" ></textarea></td>

  <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty[]" class="form-control form-control-sn qty"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="price" name="price[]" class="form-control form-control-sn price"></td>

  <td><input type="text" name="item_total[]" jAutoCalc="{#qty} * {#price}" class="form-control itemtotal" readonly></td>

  <td><input type="hidden" name="invidfk[]" value="<?php echo $inv_code; ?>"class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: The fields that should be empty are with ids as follows:- 2 inputs with id of qty, price should be ampty after the clone, because it clones from ready markup of table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set both input fields empty with  `$new.find("input").val("");`

Complete code:

```
$('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
    var $top = $table.find('tr[name=line_items]').first();
    var $bottom = $table.find('tr[name=endin_colz]').first();
    var $new = $top.clone(true);
    $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $new.find("input").val("");
    $new.insertBefore($bottom);
    autoCalcSetup();    
});
```

But note that there's a general problem with your code - if you clone elements with an id and add them, your HTML isn't valid anymore as ids have to be unique. Better use classes instead.

Comment: Thank you matthias_h for your quick response, I have added the html code so that you can get the better idea of what is being cloned, its the whole tr with name line_items is cloned, when its cloned it should only empty the newly cloned qty and price you can see I am also using autocalc library for calculation.

Comment: Thank you it worked I followed your solution and changed to class names!!! Great Response my friend! and I also thank the whole community

Comment: @gratitudetags Glad I was able to help :) If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so your question will be marked as closed/solved. If you don't know how this works, just check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: Sorry the values are still cloned the added line didnt really do the trick sorry any more help will be greatly appriciated....

Comment: @gratitudetags I've made this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t5x2wgjL/ in which I commented out the autocalc-function calls as they wouldn't work without the library. Can you check if it works on your side when you remove the line $new.jAutoCalc('destroy'); ?

Comment: Yes I tried man still bringing out the values in the clone I dont know if its conflicting with bootstrap or any other codes I have its frustrating really....

Comment: @gratitudetags Sorry to hear and hope you can resolve this issue.